# Calculate Multiple break minutes inside check_in , check_out time limit

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Datatable looks like this

```
Attd_Date_Time        User_ID   Attd_Status
-------------------------------------------
2018-03-02 09:32:12   1002018   CHECK_IN
2018-03-02 11:07:06   1002018   BREAK_IN
2018-03-02 11:25:07   1002018   BREAK_OUT
2018-03-02 16:01:27   1002018   BREAK_IN
2018-03-02 16:12:23   1002018   BREAK_OUT
2018-03-03 17:42:23   1002019   CHECK_OUT
```

- `Check_Duration` is the minute difference between MIN(Check_IN) and MAX(Check_OUT)
- `Break_Duration` is the minute difference between MIN(Break_IN) and MAX(Break_OUT)

I can calculate check_duration. But the problem I am facing is what if more than one Break_IN,BREAK_OUT involved.

Preferred output is (duration in mins) :

```
User_ID   CHECK_DURATION   BREAK_DURATION
-----------------------------------------
1002018   229              28
```

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a BREAK_IN without a following BREAK_OUT?

Comment: have u tried anything so far ?

Comment: Could someone also (somehow) end up with 2 `BREAK_IN` or `BREAK_OUT` entries in succession, without the other?

Comment: Also, how do you get the value 29 for `BREAK_DURATION`? Your description states you want the difference (I assume minutes?) between the `MIN(Break_IN)` AND `MAX(Break_OUT)`. That results in `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2018-03-02 11:07:06','2018-03-02 16:12:23')` (which is 305, not 29). I actually imagine you mean `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2018-03-02 11:07:06','2018-03-02 11:25:07') + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2018-03-02 16:01:27','2018-03-02 16:12:23')` (which **is** 29), however, that is not what you describe. You might want to reconsidering rewording your definitions.

Comment: If there is more than one Break_IN, BREAK_OUT then there will still be one MIN(Break_IN) and one MAX(Break_OUT).  VTC not clear

Comment: Hey @Larnu second part is what i mentioned in question DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2018-03-02 11:07:06','2018-03-02 11:25:07') + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2018-03-02 16:01:27','2018-03-02 16:12:23')

Comment: @Shankar but that isn't the expression `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Break_In), MAX(Break_Out))`. As I said, that would be a value of 305. Also, the value of `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2018-03-02 11:07:06','2018-03-02 11:25:07') + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2018-03-02 16:01:27','2018-03-02 16:12:23') ` is **29**; your question has a value of 28.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
 SELECT 
       DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(Attendance), MAX(Attendance)) AS Check_Duration,
        DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(CASE Status WHEN 'BREAK_IN' THEN Attendance END), MAX(CASE Status WHEN 'BREAK_OUT' THEN Attendance END)) AS BREAK_DURATION
       FROM #temp WHERE User_ID  =1002018
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @yahya but still your query will return minutes between min(Break) and max(Break).

Comment: Do you not need minutes between min(Break) and max(Break)?

Comment: are you there Shankar?

Comment: not the minutes between min(Break) and Max(Break) but you can see there is two breaks, first break is between 2018-03-02 11:07:06 and 2018-03-02 11:25:07 and second break is between 2018-03-02 16:01:27 and 2018-03-02 16:12:23. i need minutes difference between two separate breaks. like first break has 18 mins and second break has 11 mins so total break time is 29 mins.